# Full Bleed TikZ with Crop and Registration Marks

Tags: margins, geometry, printing

I've created some card-sized pages that I now need to adapt for full-bleed printing and trimming. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0in, multi=tikzpicture, varwidth=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (2.5, 3.5);
    \draw[fill=green] (0.25, 3.25) rectangle (2.25, 2.25);
    \draw[fill=red] (2, 1.5) rectangle (3.5, 2);
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0.25, -1) rectangle (0.75, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
    \clip (-0.125, -0.125) rectangle (2.625, 3.625);
    \draw[fill=green] (0.25, 3.25) rectangle (2.25, 2.25);
    \draw[fill=red] (2, 1.5) rectangle (3.5, 2);
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0.25, -1) rectangle (0.75, 1);

    \draw[help lines] (0, 0) rectangle (2.5, 3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first page shows what the document will look like once trimmed, and the second is an approximation of what should be sent to the printer--an extra 0.125in on each side so that shapes that should run off the edge make it all the way there. The final trimmed size is shown by the grey rectangle.

I need to add trim and registration marks to this document. The `crop` package is made for this, but doesn't seem to handle the "full bleed" case where parts of the document are supposed to appear outside the logical page very well. Some playing with `geometry` options allows me to get something passable, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips=false, pdftex=false, vtex=false]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        paperwidth = 2.5in,
        paperheight = 3.5in,
        margin = 0in,
        layouthoffset = -0.125in,
        layoutvoffset = -0.125in
    }
\usepackage[center, width=2.75in, height=3.75in, pdftex, cam, noinfo]{crop}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
    \clip (-0.125, -0.125) rectangle (2.625, 3.625);
    \draw[fill=green] (0.25, 3.25) rectangle (2.25, 2.25);
    \draw[fill=red] (2, 1.5) rectangle (3.5, 2);
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0.25, -1) rectangle (0.75, 1);

    \draw[help lines] (0, 0) rectangle (2.5, 3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There's two problems with this solution, however:

1. the `crop` package's registration marks (the circles with crosses) are far off the page.
2. there's an extra blank page at the start of the document, likely due to `Overfull \vbox (18.06744pt too high) has occurred while \output is active`. There's also `Overfull \hbox (18.06746pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 25--26`. Both of these are the same size, and I think relate to the width of the bleed area I've specified.

(1) can be solved by adding some circles with crosses by hand in the TikZ picture--that's not the end of the world.

(2) is a bit more annoying though. I'd prefer not to have the extra page or all the "unnecessary" errors.

Unfortunately, `crop` and the `standalone` document class don't get along well at all.

Is there a better way to handle these requirements?

Comment: I think you could use geometry and crop to define the page size with marks and later on include the standalone graphics with `includegraphics`,   `pdfpages` or even `eso-pic` and position it where you need it.